# Crypto JS AES-128 cipher - equivalent Javascript code

Tags: java, javascript, cryptojs

I have the following Java code for creating an AES-128 cipher, where key and iv are both based on the same passphrase.

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
byte[] keyBytes = new byte[16];
byte[] b = passphare.getBytes("UTF-8");
int len = b.length;
if (len > keyBytes.length) {
    len = keyBytes.length;
}

System.arraycopy(b, 0, keyBytes, 0, len);
SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(keyBytes);
cipher.init(opmode, keySpec, ivSpec);

cipher.doFinal(textToEncrypt.getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

I have tried to use the same approach in Javascript using CryptoJS for generating the same cipher, but with no success. Can you please help me?

Comment: Can you provide a short sample input & output? This would make it easier to write & test an equivalent cryptojs version. Also, can you add your current best-effort cryptojs attempt?

Comment: Yes, sure! This is what I tryed so far http://jsfiddle.net/jonaix/hgAZM/

Comment: FYI this is not secure. You are converting a password directly into bytes and using that as a key. You should use the password to generate a secure key using a password based key derivation function, like PBKDF or bcrypt or scrypt. Your IV is also not random either, which is not secure. See crypto.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @JoaoAlmeida with this jsfiddle I am getting error as `TypeError: encrypted.ciphertext is undefined`

Answer (score 1):

Quoting the JSFiddle from the OP's comment:

```
var salt = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(128/8);
// Key and iv should be based on the same value. In this example "1111"
var key = CryptoJS.PBKDF2("1111", salt, { keySize: 128/32 });
var iv = key; // Not sure what should be here!!
```

You are generating a key from a random salt (see first line), and using that same key as initialization vector... and yet you expect a constant result? (as expected, the result changes in each invocation).

Fix it to use the exact same bytes for `key` and `iv` used by the `SecretKeySpec` and `IvParameterSpec` from the java code (which you can query using their `getEncoded()` methods). I do not know whether the AES SecretKeySpec uses PBKDF2 or another key derivation function -- but it should be easy to test. Find the one that matches and stick to it.

Beware also that the default padding in CryptoJS is PKCS7 (see [the docs](http://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/#Block_Modes_and_Padding) on "block modes and padding"); this may differ strongly from the PKCS5 that you specify in your first line of Java code.